# How can I write an adapter for my React Final Form component with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

I need to write an adapter for a component, to which I need to pass certain props. For example, I have a component which can receive certain props as "disabled", but I cannot indicate it in the tag of react form. I need to do this using typescript

In React final Form :

```
<Field name="email" component={mycomponent}>
</Field>
```

"mycomponent" is the one I need to be able to pass a prop, for example "disabled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All props other than [FieldProps](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps) are passed down to the component. So you could write:

```
<Field name="email" component={MyComponent} disabled={true}>
</Field>
```

than `MyComponent` would receive `disabled` prop.